# Get error when assign the value on the dataitem on aspx page on vb code

Tags: asp.net

I searched the web and found the example. However I got the conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type String is not valid. Hope someone can show me the correct way to do it. I want to show the blank if the dataitem is null. If it has value which is from sql server like this '2013-06-10 00:00:00.000', I would like to display as '10Jun2013' on the datagrid

There is my code on aspx apge:

```
<asp:templatecolumn headertext="RecordDate" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" Itemstyle-wrap="true">
                                        <itemtemplate>                          
<%#IIf(Eval("RecordDate") Is DBNull.Value, " ", Eval(Container.DataItem, "RecordDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")%>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out  and work.

```
<%#IIf(Eval("RecordDate") Is DBNull.Value, " ", 
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RecordDate", "{0:d MMM yyyy}").ToUpper %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Text='<%# Eval("RecordDate").Equals(DBNull.value)?" ":Eval("RecordDate"))%>'
```